# Mostrar Informacion de Usuarios (FireBase, Android)

Tags: android, firebase

Buenas, tengo una BBDD en FireBase con sus Usuarios, y unos Avisos, cada apartado tiene su informacion etc..

He conseguido llegar a mostrar los Avisos (sobre el Usuario que esta logeado en la APP), ahora necesito mostrar la Informacion sobre el Usuario que esta logeado, pero no consigo hacer que funcione. Ya que despues de entrar en Usuario, busca la Uid, y me vuelve a buscar otra Uid la cual dice que es Apellidos y es cuando salta el error, ya que no hay otra Uid, que tendria que cambiar para que llegara a funcionar?

Muchas gracias

[image: FireBase]

**Codigo Mostrar Usuarios**

```
public class VerUsuario extends Registro
{

    FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    FirebaseUser user = firebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();

    List<Usuario> usuarios;
    RecyclerView recycler;
    RecyclerView.Adapter adapter;

//    Button atras;
//    Button editar;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.verusuario);

//        atras = (Button) findViewById(R.id.atras);
//        editar = (Button) findViewById(R.id.editar);

        usuarios = new ArrayList<>();

        recycler = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recycler);
        recycler.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
        adapter = new UserAdapter(usuarios);
        recycler.setAdapter(adapter);

        database.getReference("Usuario").child(user.getUid()).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                usuarios.clear();
                for(DataSnapshot snapshot :
                    dataSnapshot.getChildren())
                {
                    Log.e("Hola, error!,",snapshot.toString());
                    Usuario usuario2 = snapshot.getValue(Usuario.class);
                    usuarios.add(usuario2);
                }
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
    }
```

** Codigo Adaptador**

```
public class UserAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<UserAdapter.UserViewHolder>
{
    private List<Usuario> usuarios;

    public UserAdapter(List<Usuario> usuarios)
    {
        this.usuarios = usuarios;
    }

    @Override
    public UserViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.cardview_usuarios, parent, false);
        return new UserViewHolder(v);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(UserViewHolder holder, int position) {
        Usuario users = usuarios.get(position);
        holder.nombre.setText(users.getNombre());
        holder.apellidos.setText(users.getApellidos());
        holder.dni.setText(users.getDni());
        holder.email.setText(users.getDni());
    }


    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return usuarios.size();
    }

    public class UserViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder
    {
        public TextView nombre;
        public TextView apellidos;
        public TextView dni;
        public TextView email;

        public UserViewHolder(View v) {
            super(v);
            nombre = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.nombre);
            apellidos = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.descripcion);
            dni = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.ubicacion);
            email = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.email);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: No se si ya lo solucionaste, yo me se la respuesta utilizando menos de 4 lineas de codigo , si solo de mostrar la informacion del usuario actual se trata.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Estás haciendo un ciclo sobre tu `nodo` del id de tu **usuario**. Debes eliminar el ciclo porque ya tienes la referencia de tu **usuario**. Es decir, `database.getReference("Usuario").child(user.getUid())`

Intenta esto:

```
database.getReference("Usuario").child(user.getUid()).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            usuarios.clear();

             Usuario usuario2 = dataSnapshot.getValue(Usuario.class);
             usuarios.add(usuario2);

            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
```

Si quieres obtener información de cada usuario entonces haz esto:

```
database.getReference("Usuario").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                usuarios.clear();
                for(DataSnapshot snapshot :
                    dataSnapshot.getChildren())
                {
                    Usuario usuario2 = snapshot.getValue(Usuario.class);
                    usuarios.add(usuario2);
                }
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
```

Comment: Despues de intentar la primera solucion, me sale este error 
                    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference
                                                                                      at com.example.dam.proyectocristian.BDUsuarios.UserAdapter.onBindViewHolder(UserAdapter.java:52)                                                                                    at com.example.dam.proyectocristian.BDUsuarios.UserAdapter.onBindViewHolder(UserAdapter.java:17)

Comment: Te copio el codigo del Adaptador? Ya que el error me lo muestra en ese codigo

Comment: Tengo los mismos nombres, nombre, apellidos, dni y email. Lo de validar antes del .setText() a que te refieres exactamente? La linea que me da error es la de apellidos -         holder.apellidos.setText(users.getApellidos()); y luego public class UserAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<UserAdapter.UserViewHolder>

Comment: Esta como "Prieto Beltran", solo que no lo muestra todo el Firebase, pero si esta la ", que mas de una vez he ido a comprobarlo ^^, el correo sale igual, pero como esta tachado no puedes verlo

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/58041/discussion-between-cristian-prieto-beltran-and-andrespengineer).